# ASP.Net MVC Form binding with Model sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC and try to learning through googling & online tutorial.
i search Form binding with Model sample in MVC and got many sample code but i am not getting a sample code for a complete form where all kind of html controls are used like

```
checkbox
radiobutton
listbox control
drodownlist
textarea
hiddenfields
checkboxlist
radiobuttonlist etc
```

and all controls should be bind through model with server side and client side both kind of validation. form should have two textbox one dropdown, 3 checkboxes and 2 radio button, one listbox control and if possible provide guide line to work with checkboxlist & radiolist.

if anyone knows that kind of url then plzz inform me or if possible please give me a sample code of a complete form where all the above controls will be there with model binding and validation. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

It Explains,
Rendering a Form in ASP.NET MVC Using HTML Helpers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers

Comment: can give me a link/url from where i can get desire form with all kind of html controls with model bind. thanks

Comment: @Thomas see 2nd link.

Answer (score 1):

in the Views there is a helper called Html you can use it in the view like @Html

there are all things that you wanted, for example

```
@Html.HiddenFor

@Html.RadioButtonFor

@Html.TextAreaFor
```

and so on

search for asp.net mvc Html helpers

another smaple

```
@Html.CheckBox("sameName")
@Html.CheckBox("sameName")
@Html.CheckBox("sameName")
@Html.CheckBox("sameName")
```

it will produce this html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sameName" />
<input type="checkbox" name="sameName" />
<input type="checkbox" name="sameName" />
<input type="checkbox" name="sameName" />
```

take a look at this [website](http://mvc4beginner.com/)

Comment: is there anything for checkboxes,listbox, i can have multiple set of checkboxes then how can i specify group name and divide accordingly.

Comment: i have edit the answer with another sample, if you want to change html attributes just look for other overloads of the helper

Comment: thanks. i am new and that is why like to request u that if possible please give me a sample code of a complete form where all kind of html controls will be there and bind through model. it is my request. thanks once again.

Comment: u can also give me a link where i can get desire form with model binded. thanks